# using find with multiple strings to search within larger string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using python 2.7 I am trying to scrape title from a page, but cut it off before the closing title tag if i find one of these characters : .-_<| (as I'm just trying to get the name of the company/website) I have some code working but I'm sure there must be a simpler way. I'm open to suggestions as to libraries (beautiful soup, scrappy etc), but I would be most happy to do it without as I am happy to be slowly learning my way around python right now. You can see my code searches individually for each of the characters rather than all at once. I was hoping there was a find( x or x) function but I could not find. Later I will also be doing the same thing but looking for any numbers within 0-9 range.

```
import urllib2


opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [{'User-agent' , 'Mozilla/5.0'}]


def findTitle(webaddress):
     url = (webaddress)
     ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()
     ourUrlLower = ourUrl.lower()
     x=0
     positionStart = ourUrlLower.find("<title>",x)
     if positionStart == -1:
          return "Insert Title Here"
     endTitleSignals = ['.',',','-','_','@','+',':','|','<']
     positionEnd = positionStart + 50
     for e in endTitleSignals:              
          positionHolder = ourUrlLower.find(e ,positionStart + 1)
          if positionHolder < positionEnd and positionHolder != -1:
               positionEnd = positionHolder
     return ourUrl[positionStart + 7:positionEnd] 



print findTitle('http://www.com)
```

Comment: Does your code work? If so, try the [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get more tips on improving your code

Comment: yeah I guess thats where i should be posting this. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression library (re) could help, but if you'd like to learn more about general python instead of specialized libraries, you could do it with `sets`, which are something you'll want to know about.

```
import sets
string = "garbage1and2recycling"
charlist = ['1', '2']
charset = sets.Set(charlist)
index = 0
for index in range(len(string)):
    if string[index] in charset: break
print(index) # 7
```

Note that you could do the above using just `charlist` instead of `charset`, but that would take longer to run.

Comment: right i think (re) is what I'm looking for. Thanks for the info!